# Bash sorting commas and strings

Tags: bash, list, sorting, grep

This is the list I have, I would like it to appear as the second one (remove commas and break row before the second word)

```
jkdlfid
ljidklf,
kdjfhda,kdospad,kfmduaj,
hello
lkoplkj
```

Would like the result to be:

```
jkdlfid
ljidklf
kdjfhda
kdospad
kfmduaj
hello
lkoplkj
```

Is there any grep command for this? To clearify I would like to break row before the comma, remove the comma and then break row.

Comment: You can do `grep -Eo '[^,]+' file`. And by the way I see no connection to sorting for your problem !

Comment: @blackSmith I think you can put the comment as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

The following will do the trick :

```
grep -o '[^,]*' file
```

The idea is to match anything other than comma (`[^,]` negative character class),    zero or more times. However, I would personally use ;

```
grep -Eo '[^,]+' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily `tr`anslate commas to newlines and remove any resulting empty lines:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar,baz,ban\nbay,bat\n' | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v '^$'
foo
bar
baz
ban
bay
bat
```

Comment: OP has ending comma (your example doesn't), simply using `tr` won't get expected result...

Comment: @Kent Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**f.awk**

```
function emptyp(s) { # 1 if `s' consists of spaces and tabs
    return s ~ /^[ \t]*$/
}

{
    n = split($0, a, ",")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      if (!emptyp(a[i])) print a[i]
}
```

**f.example**

```
jkdlfid
ljidklf,
kdjfhda,kdospad,kfmduaj,
hello
lkoplkj
```

Usage:

```
awk -f f.awk f.example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tr command to do that
I am assuming that your input is in test.txt

```
tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove first and last comma by sub and then replace the two commas in between with RS new line.

```
awk'{sub(/f,/,f"")sub(/j,/,j"")}{gsub(/,/,RS)}1' file

jkdlfid
ljidklf
kdjfhda
kdospad
kfmduaj
hello
lkoplkj
```